# In the snake_case convention, should general or specific entry come first?

Tags: naming-conventions

In the snake_case convention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case, for example, `snake_case`, it seems `snake` is a specific type of `case` (there is `CamelCase`)

Is more common to put the specific thing first? E.g., `list_fruit` vs `fruit_list` in naming variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for non-boolean variables it's a good practice to let the last word in the identifier be a noun which describes the variable in a general sense. In your example it would be `fruit_list` or simply `fruits`. For boolean variables it's a good practice to let the last word be an adjective; compare for instance `fruits_rotten` with `rotten_fruits`. I would say the strategy of naming and the clarity of identifiers is independent of whether you use snake case or Pascal case, or any other convention.

Here is my general strategy for naming identifiers:

- Variables or functions without side-effects

  - Truth value -> Adjective as the last word (e.g. `fruits_rotten`)
  - Non-truth value -> Noun as the last word (e.g. `rotten_fruits`)
- Functions with side-effects (Procedures) -> Verb as the first word (e.g. `discard_rotten_fruits`)